# Quoting for incremental model partitions to replace - dbt v0.17.2

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

I'm writing an incremental model for BigQuery using the `insert_overwrite` strategy and attempting to set the `partitions_to_replace` using a variable:

```
{% set partitions_to_replace = [var('execution_date')] %}
```

Just to test compilation, I'm compiling with a variable in my `dbt_project.yml` that looks like `execution_date: '2020-01-01'`. However, it seems like **in the merge statement generated by the materialization, the date isn't quoted**, so it fails with the error `No matching signature for operator IN for argument types DATE and {INT64}`. Here's the relevant snippet of generated SQL:

```sql
when not matched by source
         and DBT_INTERNAL_DEST.visit_date in (
              2020-01-01
          )
```

Is there a way to ensure quotes around the variable? When using a variable in SQL that I've written, I know I can just wrap the `var` function in quotes, but in this case the SQL is being generated by the materialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a fair question. For flexibility, the materialization does not try to wrap the `partitions` values in quotes, as a way of supporting both SQL expressions and literals as potential inputs.

i.e. You may want the `merge` predicate to be:

```
when not matched by source
         and DBT_INTERNAL_DEST.visit_date in (
              '2020-01-01'
          )
```

but you might equally want it to be:

```
    when not matched by source
         and DBT_INTERNAL_DEST.visit_date in (
              date_sub(current_date, interval 1 day)
          )
```

As such, you'll need to either:

- pass a string literal into your `var` by wrapping in double quotes:

```
vars:
  execution_date: "'2020-01-01'"
```

- or handle the additional quoting in your `set` statement, along the lines of:

```
{% set partitions_to_replace = [] %}
{% for execution_date in [var('execution_date')] %}
    {% set ex_date %} '{{ execution_date }}' {% endset %}
    {% do partitions_to_replace.append(ex_date) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Check out [this related issue](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/issues/2506). The OP had some recommendations for syntax we could add to make this more straightforward; I'm curious to hear which of those would make sense to you.

Comment: Thanks! FYI - the jinja solution works but wrapping the `var` itself in another set of quotes doesn't. Depending on whether I put the single quotes on the outside or the double, it parses the date as either `''2020-01-01''` or `"'2020-01-01'"`

Comment: Ah, got it. Quoting is tricky. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while passing vars through the `cli`. i.e:

`dbt run --vars "execution_date: 2021-09-28"`

My workaround was the following:

- Set a `partitions_to_replace` variable.

`{%- set partitions_to_replace -%} '{{var("execution_date")}}' {%- endset -%}`

- Then in my `config` i just put this variable inside a `list`

`partitions = [partitions_to_replace]`

- Finally, to render the variable inside the SQL model, just invoke it like:

`partition_date = {{partitions_to_replace}}`